# Make common function of select by property from array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have four functions of select from array by different properties.

```
if ($scope.filters.filter1)
    $scope.filteredEntries = $scope.filteredEntries.filter(function (o)
    {
       return o.field1 === $scope.filters.filter1
    });

if ($scope.filters.filter2)
    $scope.filteredEntries = $scope.filteredEntries.filter(function (o)
    {
       return o.field2 === $scope.filters.filter2
    });
```

This code is repeatable, which is not good. I would like to put select in separate function. But select condition is different in all cases. Can I use condition as parameter or something? How can I do that?

I would like to do something like in this pseudo code:

```
expression = e => e.field == value;
miniFilter(expression);
...
function miniFilter(expression)
{
   $scope.filteredEntries = $scope.filteredEntries.filter(function (expression)
   {
      return expression;
   });
 }
```

Hope my intent is clear. I am not very good familiar with js' methodology, so pardon me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for initially presented repeated code:

```js
var data = [
  {field1: 'Tom', field2: 30}, 
  {field1: 'Max', field2: 30}, 
  {field1: 'Max', field2: 30}
];
var $scope = { filters: {
    filter1: 'Max',
    filter2: 30
  }
};

function MiniFilter(input, filters) {
  for (var prop in filters) {
    var filVal = filters[prop];
    if (filVal)
      input = input.filter(function(item) {        
        return item['field' + prop.match(/\d+$/)[0]] == filVal;
      });
  }
  return input;
}

var result = MiniFilter(data, $scope.filters);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Solution via *"expressions"*:

```js
var data = [
  {field1: 'Tom', field2: 30}, 
  {field1: 'Max', field2: 30}, 
  {field1: 'Max', field2: 30}
];
var $scope = {filters: [
  function(x){ return x.field1 == 'Max';},
  function(x){ return x.field2 == 30;}
]};

function MiniFilter(input, expressions){
  for(var exp of expressions)
    input = input.filter(exp);
  return input
}

var result = MiniFilter(data, $scope.filters);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```